# Can I travel to the USA without funds? How can I go about it?

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, tickets, airports

My friend purchased a ticket for my flight but I am actually low on funds. Is it safe to travel without any money? Will custom officers give me entry into the states?

Comment: How long is your trip?

Comment: Have you met your friend through the internet, and you are going to visit him? Do you have a credit/debit card? From where are you traveling?

Comment: I’m gonna change my question because all i want to know is will the custom officers give me entry into the states without money

Comment: It is the immigration officers who will hold you back if they feel you do not have enough money and they can. Whether they will depends on what you tell and whether you can convince them you will have enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The onus will be on you to demonstrate that you can support yourself while visiting any country (and particularly, in my experience, the US).  This need not be in cash, but you need to show you have adequate resources (credit card capacity, etc.) to be able to pay for yourself.  If someone in the US will be financially responsible for you, the US border officer will look at your circumstances to decide what (s)he believes the odds of you actually leaving the US on schedule will be.  You wlil not be allowed to work, remember.

(This assumes you're not a US citizen, in which case you have a right of entry, even if you have no money.)

Answer (score 4):

There are no rules against it but that is seriously unwise. There are people who do it and I see them at some places with signs saying *travelling, no money, please help* or something similar. The only thing to say is *don't*. If you cannot afford to go somewhere yet, work, save money then go.

Sure, some people may help you but do you really want to count on that? You may not get the help for nothing and I know women who have traded to spend the night or for meals but that is risky behavior.

It is possible to travel with someone else's money but I still suggest you go with some of your own. A company sometimes pays for travel and they usually will have the tickets and hotels paid in advance but you still have to pay for airport transfers, phone calls and meals, even if you will get paid back.

While money is needed, you do not have to have it in the bank. A credit card can count as money too. You can even get cash advances in case of emergency but a good deal in the US, including fast food and phones at airports accept credit cards. I have been to the US with no cash. Only tolls rarely take cards, so if you land and drive off with a rental car, be careful to avoid toll roads.